# how can i get java if statment promopt a user with error message when a number out of the range

Tags: java, conditional-statements

i am newbie working on my assignment, the criteria is as follow :
- use conditional statement to check if the grade is outside the range of 0-101 and print error message.
-else if the grade is the range 0-101 then add the grade to the total and work out the average
of grades.
 i have the code below, which works fine but when i input a number outside the range of 0-101
no error message comes up.
can anyone help me in what i am doing wrong, any help is appreciated.
here is my code:
import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class GradeCalculator {
    public  void readGrade() {


         // 1. Creatin a Scanner using the InputStream available.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );
        // 2. Using the Scanner to read int from the user.
        // 3. returns the next double.


        }
    public void WorkOutGrade(){
         Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         //declaring the variables.
                int testScoreA;
                int testScoreB;
                int testScoreC;
                int testScoreD;
                int testScoreE;
                double sum;
               double average;
              //
         do{
            System.out.println("welcome to the grade calculator , please Enter a grade between 0-101 ");
            System.out.print("And press enter key on your keyboard to type the next score, ");
            System.out.println("please Enter your first test score: ");
            testScoreA = keyboard.nextInt();
          if (testScoreA >= 0 && testScoreA  < 101   );
         else if (testScoreA < 0 && testScoreA  > 101  )

            System.out.print("wront input ");
            System.out.print("Enter your second test score: ");
            testScoreB = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter your third test score: ");
            testScoreC = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter your fourth test score: ");
            testScoreD = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter your fifth test score: ");
            testScoreE = keyboard.nextInt();
            keyboard.nextLine();
             sum =(testScoreA+testScoreB+ testScoreC+ testScoreD+ testScoreE/2);
            average=sum/4;
            System.out.println(" your grades are: "+" grade 1 = "+testScoreA+ 
                    " grade 2 = " +testScoreB+ " grade 3 = "+ testScoreC+ " grade 4 = "+ testScoreD+ " grade 5 = "+ testScoreE);
            System.out.println("your grade average is :"+ average+".");
           } while (testScoreA >= 0 && testScoreA  < 101   );
          if (testScoreA < 0 && testScoreA  > 101  )
            System.out.print("wront input ");
         else  System.out.println(); 

          keyboard.close();
         }

}
```

Comment: Here's something to ponder about..`else if (testScoreA < 0 && testScoreA  > 101  )`..can a number be both lesser than 0 and greater than 101?

Comment: yes, when a user inputs e.g  -10 or 105

Comment: like i said i am a newbie in java :-)

Comment: And what about 101. There once was an airplane that on take off handled speed < 100 mph and speed > 100 mph. Guess.

Comment: no clue, i am a newbie in this, i am thinking of it where by the user is prompted with an error message if he puts a number outside the range of 101 e.g 105 or 106..

Comment: Okay..can a *single* number be both lesser than 0 and greater than 101? Isn't that what you're implying when you write `else if (testScoreA < 0 && testScoreA > 101 )`..that statement is to be read as else if testScoreA lesser than 0 *and* testScoreA greater than 101

Comment: do think i should us || instead of &&

Comment: You should always use `curly brackets { }` around your blocks, such as `if(something.equals(whatever)) { System.out.println("Hello!"); }` because lack of brackets can cause hidden errors later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example, where you read 5 grades (repeating if they are not correct) and print the average:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GradeCalculator {



//Maximum number of grades
    private static final int NUM_SCORES = 5;
    public void readGrade() {

        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // declaring the variables.
        int sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the grade calculator , please Enter a grade between 0-101 ");
        System.out.println("And press enter key on your keyboard to type the next score:");

        for (int i = 0; i < NUM_SCORES; i++) {
            int testScore;
            do {
                System.out.println("Please enter your test score:");
                testScore = keyboard.nextInt();
                //if the score is not correct: Output Error
                if (testScore < 0 || testScore > 101)
                    System.err.println("Wront input. Inpute the test score again!");
                else{
                    //if the score is correct, then add the score to the sum
                    sum += testScore;
                }
                //repeat if the score is not correct, to get a correct score
            }while (testScore < 0 || testScore > 101);
        }
        //The average is the sum of the scores divided by the number of scores
        System.out.println("Your grade average is :" + sum/NUM_SCORES);

        keyboard.close();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GradeCalculator().readGrade();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use an or instead of an and for your error condition:

So instead of:

```
else if (testScoreA < 0 && testScoreA  > 101  )
```

You should use:

```
else if (testScoreA < 0 || testScoreA  > 101  )
```

With your first line, you are checking for a number that is smaller than 0 and bigger than 101. As far as I know, that is impossible.
So if you use an or (||) you will check if the number is smaller than 0 or bigger than 101

Comment: Only that wont solve his problem... Because do{} part will execute atleast once..it will accept 6 numbers even if they are out of range..

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was just focusing in the specific error, but there is a lot of things to fix in here.

Comment: is because where i placed the do loop or where i closed it!

Comment: Because how you have your program, you are only checking that the score is correct for testScoreA, but the rest of scores will never be checked, so you can input the scores (50,-999,999,12345,-1) and it will not show any error, because the first score is correct.

Comment: Also, in this case, you only have 5 scores, and you can do it in separate variables, but I would use an array to make the code more clear and easier.

Comment: yeah i thought of an array but my assignment doesn't ask for it, so inserting an array here wont help. can you show me an exsample